# Black color is not visible when a overlay also have black background with opacity

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a overlay with a button.

Button has black color background and the overlay also have black color background with opacity 0.6.

My problem is i can not see the black background of the button.

Sample [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MbLNN/128/) is here. Please find the screenshot too.[image]

HTML

```
<section id="s-explore">
    <div class="pagebreak"><span>The Lifestyle</span>  <i class="down">&lt;</i>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper layout">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="media">
                <img id="d1" src="http://placekitten.com/300/300" />
                <div class="contenthover">                  

                    <p><a href="#" class="mybutton">Lorem ipsum</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

CSS

```
.contenthover{
    color:#fff;
}
.mybutton{    
    padding:20px;
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#000;
    margin:10px;
}
```

Jquery

```
 $(function () {
     $(' #d1').contenthover({
         overlay_width: 300,
         overlay_height: 150,
         effect: 'slide',
         slide_direction: 'bottom',
         overlay_x_position: 'center',
         overlay_y_position: 'bottom',
         overlay_background: '#000',
         overlay_opacity: 0.8
     });
 });
```

Comment: Your screen shot does not appear to match your jsFiddle. In the jsFiddle you have a slide-to-reveal section and a button over that, both of which have a black background with 0.8 opacity.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MbLNN/129/ there - fixed, based on the GolezTrol comment

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The button will inherit its opacity from the parent, so an opacity of 1 will actually be 0.8.

To fix this, make the background opaque as well, and specify a color with an alpha value instead:

```
/* overlay_opacity: 0.8  This be gone */
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
```

See also: [A brief introduction to Opacity and RGBA](http://www.css3.info/introduction-opacity-rgba/)

Answer (score 1):

use color rgba instead hex and opacity.

opacity attach all element opacity but rgba only curent element.

rgba(0,0,0, 0.5); this is black with 0.5 opacity.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the opacity of 0.6 as it also applies to the child in this case button and replace it with

> background:rgba(0,0,0,.6);

Answer (score 1):

Only changes needed are

1. Remove `overlay_opacity: 0.8`
2. Change previous line to `overlay_background: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.8)'`

See http://jsfiddle.net/MbLNN/129

Based on [GolezTrol answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25648356/481422)

Comment: Why do you answer the question with the essentially same answer as I gave, even referring to my answer? I'm flattered of course, but does it add value?

Comment: your answer does not point to use overlay_background but to use background-color. I wanted to point out the needed changes of the current solution more clearly.